# Let $\mathfrak p, \mathfrak p' ⊂ S$ be relevant prime ideals. If $\mathfrak p \cap S_+ = \mathfrak p' \cap S_+$, then $\mathfrak p = \mathfrak p'$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, graded-rings

Let $S$ be a graded ring. Let $\mathfrak p, \mathfrak p' ⊂ S$ be relevant prime ideals.

> If $\mathfrak p \cap S_+ = \mathfrak p' \cap S_+$, then $\mathfrak p = \mathfrak p'$.

I don't see how this is always true. Is it not possible that, say, $\mathfrak p$ may have a homogeneous degree $0$ element which is not in $\mathfrak p'$?

Are all degree $0$ elements in $\mathfrak p$ also in $\mathfrak p'$, and vice versa?

Comment: Suppose $\mathfrak{p}$ has a homogeneous degree $0$ element not contained in $\mathfrak{p}'$. Would that affect the homogeneous degree-$n$ elements for any $n > 0$?

Comment: @Jackson What do you mean by affect the degree $n$ elements?

Comment: I mean in terms of the grading on $S$. What happens when you compare the intersections $S_n \cap \mathfrak{p}$ and $S_n \cap \mathfrak{p}'$, assuming $S_0 \cap \mathfrak{p} \ne S_0 \cap \mathfrak{p}'$?

Comment: @Jackson I think I see: Suppose $x \in \mathfrak p$ but $x \notin \mathfrak p'$ where $x$ is homogeneous and $\deg x =0$. Let $y \in S_n$ for any $n >0$. Then $xy \in S_n \cap \mathfrak p = S_n \cap \mathfrak p'$. So, $xy \in \mathfrak p'$. Since $x \notin \mathfrak p'$, then $y \in \mathfrak p'$. Therefore, $S_+ \subset \mathfrak p'$. Contradiction.

Comment: @Jackson Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: That's the idea. I think you should be more careful about $x$ (is it in $S_0$?) and $y$ (is it in $\mathfrak{p}$?) and the contradiction (there's a different contradiction)—but this idea can be made to work

Comment: @Jackson I edited it to include that $x$ is homogeneous of degree $0$. I'm choosing $y$ to be any element of $S_n$. Do we need to specify if it is in $\mathfrak p$ or not? The contradiction I had in mind was that $\mathfrak p'$ contains the irrelevant ideal but we assumed that it did not. What is the other contradiction?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129792/discussion-between-jackson-and-user46372819).